# Configure DNS Server internally

Tags: linux

I want to configure an internal DNS server. The name of domain which i want to use in internal domain is already registered out side. But some sub domain is running locally. Like our main domain is abc.com and sub domains are zy.abc.com and xy.abc.com. i want to access those subdomain locally using that my internal DNS server but for abc.com i want to access externally. How to configure the dns server so that it will work.

Comment: I could probably try to follow the https://wiki.debian.org/Bind9 tutorial, perfect to put in place some local dns.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure and run some DNS servers and make them locally accessible to your network. You can also configure the same DNS server to serve internal and external clients.

You did not tell us the DNS server you are using. If you are using [bind9](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/view.html), you can use `view` config option to configure several different views for the same zone based on client IP addresses. So, the available domain names and IPs can be different based on who is requesting name resolution.